# different styles on homepage and posts wordpress

Tags: wordpress, css

I am a newbie in design/dev but want to learn fast. Its a Wordpress site, I cant figure out how to style homepage and posts differently. When i change settings in the theme options, it changes everything uniformly. Here is the site: http://blog.kaprayonline.pk/

See the magazine style blocks on the main page, i want their body font to be 12 and title 14.
and when i click on those links, the post font i want size 14 and title 42. I have looked at style.css and made so many changes to the child theme but am unsuccessful so far.

Also i am trying to create a block or container like here (ones in the body): blog.motelrocks.com and so far have got to know about masonry script but still clueless on how to go about making such blocks..help please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use WordPress `body_class()` to attach a list of classes to `<body>` element according to type of page being displayed.

This will help you to differentiate between 'Home Page' and 'Posts'. You can find further details here http://quirm.net/2009/08/07/changing-headers-with-wordpress-body_class/

Update:

Just checked, your theme already attaches class `home` to the `<body>` element of home page while it attaches `single` as class to `<body>` element of posts. So now using CSS Selectors you can easily write CSS differentiating your home page and posts page.

A simple example could be

```
.home div {
 background-color: #fff;
}

.single div {
 background-color: #000;
}
```

This will paint all `Div` of home page with white color and all `Div` in posts with black color background.

Visit this link for details about CSS Selectors https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors

Comment: Got it done but had to use trial and error a lot:  
  
`.single .entry p {
font: 300 14px/1.5em "OpenSans",Open Sans, sans-serif;
}`

Comment: Glad it helped you. Please accept it as correct answer if this solved your problem. This will help others by not wasting time on an already solved question.